# WiX Toolset: how to conditionally install component during modify or repair

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX based installer which, among other things, conditionaly installs a desktop shortcut for my app. To achieve that, I’m using the `WixUI_InstallDir` UI (because I have a single feature), and I modified the `VerifyReadyDlg` dialog to show a checkbox linked to a property that is used in a condition of the Shortcut component.

Relevant code:

```
<Property Id="INSTALLDESKTOPSHORTCUT" Secure="yes" />

...

<Component Id="desktop_shortcut" Guid="xyz">
    <Condition>INSTALLDESKTOPSHORTCUT</Condition>
    <Shortcut Id="desktopshortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="The Name"
              WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Icon='app.ico' IconIndex="0" Target="[#app.exe]" />
    <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='the/key' Type='string'
                   Name='desktop_shortcut_key' Value='1' KeyPath='yes' />
</Component>

...

<Feature Id='Complete' Level='1'>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id='the_app' />
    <ComponentRef Id='desktop_shortcut' />
</Feature>
```

This works perfectly during the initial install of the app and also during a major upgrade. That is, when the user runs the MSI in one of these scenarios, they get the checkbox during the last step of the installer and the shortcut is correctly installed or not based on the user choice.

However, if the user runs again the same installer, it will enter the `MaintenanceTypeDlg` that allows to chose between **Modify**, **Repair** and **Uninstall** (I have activated the modify option through the `ARPNOMODIFY` property). And, when going through the modify or repair flow, they will see my modified UI, they can check or uncheck the checkbox for the desktop shortcut but it has no effect. When the installer is run in one of these two modes, the shortcut is never changed (it is neither installed nor removed).

This kind of makes sense in repair mode but, when using the modify option, I would expect that the set of installed components can be changed. Is there a way to achieve that? Am I doing something wrong?

Note: I suspect that this would work if I were using a `Feature` to install the shortcut. I’m not doing that for two reasons: this does not match the standard UI (shortcuts are usually selected through a custom checkbox rather than as a feature inside the feature tree) and using that approach requires that the components for all of my app be included in the shortcut feature (otherwise the shortcut refers to a different feature), and this messes up the install size computation (the shortcut alone is shown as taking xx MB).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting **Transitive** flag to **yes** for the affected component.

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/component.html

Comment: Thanks, this partly fix the situation: the user choice is now taken into account during a "repair" operation but, interestingly, still not during a "modify" operation. Given that I have a single feature, I can probably live without support for "modify", but I’m surprised as I would have expected that supporting the "modify" flow would be easier.

Comment: Yes. During modify, REINSTALL property is not set but repair does set this property. You need to set REINSTALL~="ALL" in modify flow maybe through custom action/command-line. Overall, it would mean you are triggering repair too in modify flow.